# Autorotate Screen Error After return from webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I use cocos combined with admob , nomarl my app work great, but after hit the advertising and return the game, it wrong layout

this is my rotation code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );
}

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect rect;

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)     
        rect = screenRect;
else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        rect.size = CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.height, screenRect.size.width);

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    EAGLView *glView = [director openGLView];
    float contentScaleFactor = [director contentScaleFactor];

    if (contentScaleFactor != 1) {
        rect.size.width *= contentScaleFactor;
        rect.size.height *= contentScaleFactor;
    }
    glView.frame = rect;
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue before, and what I did incorrectly was that I created a new UIViewController and set it as `rootViewController` for AdMob view. What I am doing now in my app is like:

```
adMobView.rootViewController = [RootViewController sharedInstance];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:adMobView];
```

where `[RootViewController sharedInstance]` is a class method which returns the only instance of RootViewController in the app. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10222956/1241690.

(For cocos2d 2.x, the second line should be:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:adMobView];
```

)